# Extracting road data from shapefile using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, select, arcgis-10.5

I have a road network shapefile of a city. I want to extract those roads which have 80ft or more than that width.

Is there any tool in ArcMap to extract the data?